# Disable RecyclerView scroll and enable ViewPager Scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I have a recyclerView inside a viewPager i have disabled scroll for Recyclerview but the problem is that when i try to swipe on the recyclerview, viewpager doesn't scroll, nothing happens. I tried few solutions but nothing helped.
Below is my code snippet.

```
public class LockableViewPagerMainActivity extends ViewPager {
    private boolean swipeable;

    public LockableViewPagerMainActivity(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public LockableViewPagerMainActivity(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.swipeable = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.swipeable) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.swipeable) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void setSwipeable(boolean swipeable) {
        this.swipeable = swipeable;
    }
}
```

RecyclerView :

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.SimpleOnItemTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
                // true: consume touch event
                // false: dispatch touch event
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

This disables scrolling of RecyclerView